# Realm Android example in Android Studio are not working

Tags: realm

I follow [these](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#examples) instructions to get the examples working in Android Studio but I get problems with Gradle (as shown in image and video below).

Any idea on how to fix this ?

This happens with [current](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/commit/5106612ed22540e397f516fb572d0389096b0f1d) master branch.

[image]

Here is a short video screen capture showing how this happens : https://youtu.be/H7djFyrxPxY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v1.1.0` branch (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/v1.1.0) instead of `master` should work fine.

Or you need to  execute `./gradlew installRealmJava` before importing examples to build and install latest SNAPSHOT.

Comment: If I remember correctly you have to call `./gradlew assemble` from the root folder first if doing a clean checkout.

Comment: I tried this but it gave me some strange error: http://lpaste.net/173110, any ideas on that ? " failed to find target with hash string 'android-24' in: /Users/joco/.android-sdk" - even though I have api - 24 installed

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are definitely using `1.2.0-SNAPSHOT` without adding the SNAPSHOT repository

```
    maven {
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
```

That could be causing this problem.